# Is there a userspace bandwith limit tool for Linux?

Tags: linux, bandwidth, qos, udp, p2p

I want to limit the upload bandwidth of a P2P live video program, which is closed source, in Linux.

I don't want to use `tc` because I don't have root access. There is a tool called `trickle`, but unfortunately it doesn't handle UDP (the P2P program mainly uses UDP).

Is there any other way to throttle bandwidth of a program in Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use force_bind to set the bandwidth. Check the README file for an example.

http://kernel.embedromix.ro/us/

Disclaimer: I am the author.

Comment: Great work! I'll have a look.